# How do I reason with Skolem functions?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, alternative-proof

Given the first-order sentence.

$\forall x \forall y : (Overlap(x,y) \iff  (\exists z Part(z,x) \land Part(z,y)))~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$  (**1**)

Here is an outline (partial) proof that $Overlap$ is symmetric:

**Proof 1**
\begin{align}
& \text{1}~~\forall x \forall y : (Overlap(x,y) \iff  (\exists z Part(z,x) \land Part(z,y))) & \tag{Axiom}\\
&  \text{2}~~~~~~~Overlap(a,b) \tag{Assume} \\
&  \text{3}~~~~~~~\exists z (Part(z,a) \land Part(z,b)) \tag{1,2}\\
&  \text{4}~~~~~~~\exists z (Part(z,b) \land Part(z,a)) \tag{3}\\
&  \text{5}~~~~~~~Overlap(b,a)  \tag{1,2,4}\\
&  \text{6}~~\forall x \forall y : (Overlap(x,y) \implies Overlap(y,x)) \tag{$\forall$-Intro 2-5} \\
\end{align}
Note in line 4 the same existential $z$ is used.

Now I wish write the  axiom (**1**) in an [equisatisfiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equisatisfiability) form that can be proved using equational logic and term rewriting. This usually requires Skolemization.  Sentence (**1**) can be Skolemized as follows:

$\forall x \forall y : (Overlap(x,y) \iff   (Part(Sk(x,y),x) \land Part(Sk(x,y),y))~~~~~~~~~~~$ (**2**)

Now I try to prove symmetry using (**2**) with a similar approach as in **Proof 1**:

**Proof Attempt 2**
\begin{align}
& \text{1}~~\forall x \forall y : (Overlap(x,y) \iff   (Part(Sk(x,y),x) \land Part(Sk(x,y),y))& \tag{Axiom}\\
&  \text{2}~~~~~~~~Overlap(a,b) \tag{Assume} \\
&  \text{3}~~~~~~~~Part(Sk(a,b),a) \land Part(Sk(a,b),b)  \tag{1,2}\\
&  \text{4}~~~~~~~~Part(Sk(a,b),b) \land Part(Sk(a,b),a)  \tag{3}\\
&  \text{5}~~~~~~~~Overlap(b,a)\tag{XX}\\
&  \text{6}~~\forall x \forall y : (Overlap(x,y) \implies Overlap(y,x)) \tag{XX} \\
\end{align}

I am stuck at lines 4-5 in **Proof Attempt 2**.By following the approach of **Proof 1** there is an issue with the order of arguments to Skolem functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sketch of the main idea. The axiom is the same if the  universal quantifiers are interchanged.

Skolemization of this gives
$$\exists Sk \forall y \forall x \; Overlap(x, y) \Leftrightarrow Part(Sk(y, x), x) \land Part(Sk(y, x), y) \tag{a}\label{eqa}$$

which is equivalent to

$$\exists Sk \forall x \forall y \; Overlap(y, x) \Leftrightarrow Part(Sk(x, y), y) \land Part(Sk(x, y), x) \tag{b}\label{eqb}$$

by changing the names of the variables.

We can also show similarly from the Axiom that

$$\exists S \forall x \forall y \; Overlap(x, y) \Leftrightarrow Part(S(x, y), y) \land Part(S(x, y), x) \tag{c}\label{eqc}$$

From (\ref{eqb}) and (\ref{eqc}) and the assumption on the Skolem functions that $\exists Sk \exists S \forall x \forall y \; Sk(x, y) = S(x, y)$, it follows

$$\forall x \forall y \;  Overlap(x,y) \Leftrightarrow Overlap(y, x) $$

Comment: Why are the "Sk"s introduced in "b" and "c" the same? (Or at the very least, why are they   *named* the same?)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried to clarify this.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks. My understanding of your solution is that the reasoning is second order because you mention equality between functions. Is it possible to prove the Skolemized version in first order logic?

Comment: I also don't get why you can say there's an interpretation where they're equal functions --- that seems to be just a claim that the last step is OK because we need it to be OK, but I'm sure there's a better reason than that. (I"m not at all a logician, so a lot of words here are relatively new to me; I don't know what an "interpretation" is, for instance.)

Comment: The idea  is that $z = Sk(x, y)$ is a witness in equation (b) and so there exists an extensionally equal function $S$ in equation (c) from the one in (b). An interpretation maps symbols to a model, e.g. it could map $x, y, z$ to sets of natural numbers. Skolemization involves quantification of a function which is second-order. I will try to give an alternative proof using resolution.

Comment: @DavidW Am I justified in adding the assumption $\forall x \forall y Sk(x,y) = Sk(y,x)$ to **Proof Attempt 2**

Comment: That would lead to a proof of something different. You can assert that there exist Skolem functions $Sk$ and $S$ such that $\forall x \forall y \; Sk(x, y) = S(x, y)$.

Comment: @Patrick Browne I am happy that you found this useful. The comments generally prompted me to express things more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

We can translate the original bi-conditional axiom into three implications. Using the quantifier equivalence, $\exists x (Q(x) \implies P) \equiv \forall x Q(x) \implies P $, the existential in the original  (**1**) can be replaced by a universal $z$, so line 3 below does not need a Skolem function. I believe these 3 sentences and the FOL sentence (**1**) are [equisatisfiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equisatisfiability). I believe breaking  (**1**) into three parts makes the proof fairly straightforward.

**Proof**
\begin{align}
& \text{1}~~\forall x \forall y : (Overlap(x,y) \implies  Part(Sk(x,y),x)) & \tag{Axiom1}\\
& \text{2}~~\forall x \forall y : (Overlap(x,y) \implies  Part(Sk(x,y),y))& \tag{Axiom2}\\
& \text{3}~~\forall x \forall y \forall z : ((Part(z,x) \land Part(z,y)) \implies Overlap(x,y))& \tag{Axiom3}\\
&  \text{4 (a,b)}~~Overlap(a,b) \tag{Assume} \\
&  \text{5}~~~~~~~~~~~~~(Part(Sk(a,b) ,a) \land Part(Sk(a,b) ,b))  \implies Overlap(a,b)   \tag{$\forall$-Elim 3}\\
&  \text{6}~~~~~~~~~~~~~Overlap(a,b)  \implies  Part(Sk(a,b),a)   \tag{$\forall$-Elim 1}\\
&  \text{7}~~~~~~~~~~~~~Overlap(a,b)  \implies  Part(Sk(a,b),b)   \tag{$\forall$-Elim 2}\\
&  \text{8}~~~~~~~~~~~~~Part(Sk(a,b),a)  \tag{$\implies$-Elim 4,6}\\
&  \text{9}~~~~~~~~~~~~~Part(Sk(a,b),b)  \tag{$\implies$-Elim 4,7}\\
&  \text{10}~~~~~~~~~~~~~Part(Sk(a,b),b)  \land  Part(Sk(a,b),a)  \tag{$\land$-Intro 8,9}\\
&  \text{11}~~~~~~~~~~~~~(Part(Sk(a,b) ,b) \land Part(Sk(a,b) ,a))  \implies Overlap(b,a)   \tag{$\forall$-Elim 3}\\
&  \text{12}~~~~~~~~~~~~~Overlap(b,a) \tag{$\implies$-Elim 10,11}\\
&  \text{13}~~\forall x \forall y : (Overlap(x,y) \implies Overlap(y,x)) \tag{$\forall$-Intro 4-12} \\
\end{align}